# history object doesn't keep navigation history ios7 safari

Tags: mobile-safari, ios7, sencha-touch-2.2

I've just noticed this issue in my sencha touch 2 app:
- If you are using Application Cache and also managing states through hash or other technique, the history object will not keep your navigation history, therefore history.back() will never work and history.length stays in 1 forever.

Any idea whether there is a workaround to solve this?

Comment: We have experienced this issue as well, but not with Sencha Touch. We've been forced to remove the use of the application cache on iOS7 as we couldn't find a way around it.

Comment: How does one "remove the use of the application cache"?